# How can my application read windows messages (WM_SETTEXT) from another application?

Tags: winapi, windows-xp, hook, interceptor

Is there a way to intercept window messages from another app other than a global message hook? Platform: Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a hook procedure by calling SetWindowHookEx function. Specify the identifier of the thread with which the hook procedure is to be associated. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: If the thread belongs to another process, the hook must be implemented in a DLL, the same as a global hook does.