# Waiting until enter key is pressed in a notepad

Tags: c#, winapi, hook

I would like to get the previous entered Text message in an open notepad instance until the ENTER key is pressed (asynchronously).

That is, enter "some text is entered [ENTER]" then I like to get the string "some text is entered" (MessageBox.show(sometext);) Would you please offer me an idea of how to do this without use of a global keyboard hook ? Thank you

Comment: This is an extremely odd question. Why on Earth would you want to do this?

Comment: Convoluted "Hello, world." example?

Comment: Are you asking how to build a key logger?

Comment: A keyboard hook is the only way I can see to do this, which would be creating a key logger.  The only alternatives would be to either re-create notepad and replace the default application with an almost identical one or send notepad the key-combination cntrl+s periodically and check the file to see what the last line says and whether it's different from when you last looked.

Comment: What's wrong with a global keyboard hook? This is what they're designed for.

Answer (score 0):

If keyboard hook does not work - consider spying on the messages sent/handled by the notepad window. Spyxx tool from Visual Studio tools will show messages (note to match 32/64 bit to be able to spy).

Note that it still requires ability to run in another process - 
[How can my application read windows messages (WM_SETTEXT) from another application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366710/how-can-my-application-read-windows-messages-wm-settext-from-another-applicati) , I would not recommend native code for doing it instead of C#.